# Why the folder name changes from 'Art' to 'aRT' in windows 10?

Tags: windows, file, windows-10, filenames

I am trying to create a new folder in windows with a name "Art", but when i press enter the name changes to "aRT".

Can you help me with a reason and suggest me what to do in such cases?

Comment: Is there already a folder with the latter name ?

Comment: How do you create the folder? Using windows explorer? Programmatically? From the command line? Any errors or return codes?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer no there is no other folder. I created a folder using right click and selected the option New folder.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Windows issues don't belong here.

Comment: Maybe Caps Lock is on?

Comment: @user2120666 hahaha, no. I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a windows update solved my issue. It auto restarted my system and this issue got resolved. Now I am able to create a folder named "Art".
Initially I suspected it's a key word reserved by windows, but looks like It's not.